# Этимология слова "кранты"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, жаргон

Каково происхождение этого слова?
Как-то довелось услышать выражение ***перекрыть кранты***, но я слабо представляю:
*в буквальном ли смысле эти **кранты** перекрывают?*
Или это жаргонное выражение?

Answer (score 1):

**[Крант](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82)** - это "испорченный" кран, см.

> Крант - *устар.* или *прост.* то же, что кран ◆ *Тараско перешёл
>   вместе с Кузьмичом в паровой корпус и его должность называлась «ходить
>   у крантов»* Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк, «Три конца», 1890 г. ◆ *Вон кранты… в
>   этом вот холодная, а здеся горячая…* С. П. Подъячев, «Мытарства», 1903
>   г. ◆ *Глаза щиплет… Намылился, а кранта не могу найти… Ироды!* В. П.
>   Катаев, «Миллион терзаний», 1930 г.

**[Кранты́](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)**, см. значение.

**Этимология**

> Происходит от *прост.* выражения: перекрыть кранты. Ср.: *Как стянул
>   её дед по лесенке на дебаркадер, тут же на бок ― плюх, завалилась,
>   подёргалась четырьмя, поикала немного ― и кранты ей завинтились.*
>   Александр Иличевский. Бутылка (2005) // «Зарубежные записки», 2008.

---

Ещё версия, но неубедительная:

**[Откуда пошло слово КРАНТЫ?](http://lifecity.com.ua/?l=knowledge&mod=view&id=7284)**

> "Словарь русского арго (материалы 1980--1990-х гг.)" сообщает о
>   возможном происхождении слова кранты из уголовного жаргона, давая ему
>   следующее определение: "1. Конец, завершение чего-л.; провал, неудача.
>   Всё, мне ~-- я пропал. 2. в зн. межд. Выражает любую эмоцию (чаще
>   отрицательную).
>
> Слово вошло в наш лексикон из уголовного, так называемого блатного
>   жаргона, а происхождение в этом словаре верное, это нам на лекциях по
>   криминалистике в академии говорили.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно, что ударение разное: кр*á*ны, но крант*ы'*. Вероятно, потому, что второй вариант — просторечный?

Comment: Ответ Галине Аванесовой: те, кто работает с кранАми, часто говорят "кранЫ" )